# sort function not working properly in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I wrote a Perl program

```
$number = <>;                       # get the number of numbers
$values = <STDIN>;                  # accept number separated by spaces

@num    = split( " ", $values );    # split the number separated by spaces
@num    = sort @num;

for ( $i = 0; $i < $number; $i++ ) {
    print $num[$i], "\n";
}
```

I gave the input as

```
4
1 7 8 100
```

The output i got was

```
1 100 7 8
```

which is wrong

Comment: This question is answered in the documentation [p3rl.org/sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) in the 3rd sentence...

Comment: It looks like you are using a rather old resource to learn Perl. You should always have `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of all your programs and declare your variables with `my`. Please take a look at the list of tutorials, books and other resources we have compiled in [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) here on SO. Learning from a high quality resource will make your life a lot easier. Have fun with Perl. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@num=sort { $a <=> $b } @num;
```

will produce what you want. Have a look at the relevant docs page: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

It doesn't sort as you want because

> If SUBNAME or BLOCK is omitted, sorts in standard string comparison order.

according to the docs!

Comment: what are $a and $b here?

Comment: $a and $b are exempt global variables. they are exempt in that Perl allows them to be used (anywhere) without being declared. They are set by the sort function.
Please refer to the docs page, there're a few examples which might help you (for example, declaring your own standalone "explicit" sort function, if you want to).

Comment: @kapil for each pair of values inside `@num`, two are compared at a time. `$a` is the left one of the two, and `$b` is the right one.

Comment: *"what are `$a` and `$b` here?"* Please *read the documentation* that you have been linked to twice. The downvotes your question received are probably because all of this is laid out clearly in the documentation; please make use of it. The question has also been answered before on Stack Overflow, and you should search for an existing solution before involving people in additional effort.